# OKTA Single Sign on for a java application

Tags: tomcat, single-sign-on, okta

I have a java web application deployed on tomcat as WAR. I want to secure this application with OKTA for SSO. My application was secured with Keycloak before. I am not clear how we can do that in OKTA. Can anyone point me to some article or documentation. I saw there was a page(https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/24880412-Okta-SAML-Toolkit-for-Java?_ga=2.131641421.373849229.1589171789-1935561743.1586824408) but it does not exist anymore.

Comment: There are some [example servlets](https://github.com/okta/samples-java-servlet) linked from Okta's developer pages.

Comment: You may just use standards based SSO technologies like SAMLv2 or OpenID connect, then it does not matter which product is being used for user authentication in the future.

Comment: Thanks, will try.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr, are you implying to use Spring security?

Comment: If your application is Spring based, then yes you may use Spring Security. There is a 'module' for SAML SSO and OIDC SSO.